# Node.js util Promisify Mongoose method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I've come across a blocker on attempting to promisify a mongoose method.
As far as my understanding goes I should be able to promisify fn's that take in callbacks with an error and a parameter, but in this case I get this error:

> **TypeError: this.Query is not a constructor**

model code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({ 
    name: String, 
    password: String, 
    admin: Boolean 
}));
```

breaking code:

```
var User = require('./app/models/user');
var { promisify } = require('util');
var findUserPromise = promisify(User.findOne);

...

    findUserPromise({ name: req.body.name })
    .then(user => console.log("do something with the user"))
    .catch(err => { console.log("err ", err) });
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongoose is already very promise-friendly.  To get a promise from `findOne()`, you just need to call `.exec()`:

Instead of

```
var findUserPromise = promisify(User.findOne);
...

findUserPromise({ name: req.body.name })
    .then(user =>
...
```

Just call it with `.exec()`
:

```
User.findOne({ name: req.body.name }).exec()
    .then(user =>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes as @Jim B answer, mongoose is promise friendly. you can also use `async` and `await`

```
const User = require('./app/models/user');

module.export = { 
  userDetails: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
      console.log(user);
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```